# Process for $(k+1)^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I've mentioned in previous questions that I have a hard time with simplifying algebraic equations.

For this equation, I assumed we would first put the equation into easier to read form:

$(k+1)(k+1)(k+1)$

Then apply FOIL to the first two:

EDIT: $(k^2+2k+1)(k+1)$

Although this is where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

With all your help my answer is:

$k^3+3k^2+3k+1$

Thanks.

Comment: Look into the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: Yes, I say that in my question.

Comment: You don't mention the binomial theorem anywhere in your question.

Comment: @Max: I think the OP was referring to my comment, which I had deleted.

Comment: @wj32 Ah. That makes sense.

Comment: You have a typo.  The trinomial should end with $+1$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your expansion of $(k+1)(k+1)$. It is supposed to be $(k^2+2k+1)$

Comment: There's a nice post on MathOverflow about FOIL, in "Most harmful heuristic?" Unfortunately, MO is down right now: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2358/most-harmful-heuristic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just multiply each pair of terms:
$$(k^2+2k+2)(k+1)=k^2\cdot k + k^2\cdot 1 + 2k\cdot k + 2k\cdot 1 + 2 \cdot k + 2 \cdot 1 $$

Of course you can also use the binomial theorem, but I'd try to master the basics first.

Comment: Ah, that's simple and easy, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use the distributive law (after correcting your first multiplication):

$$(k^2+2k+1)(\color{red}{k}+\color{blue}{1})=(k^2+2k+1)\cdot\color{red}{k}+(k^2+2k+1)\cdot\color{blue}{1}\;.$$

Now $(k^2+2k+1)\cdot k=k^3+2k^2+k$, and $(k^2+2k+1)\cdot 1=k^2+2k+1$, so all that’s left is to add the two polynomials:

$$\begin{align*}
(k^3+2k^2+k)+(k^2+2k+1)&=k^3+(2k^2+k^2)+(k+2k)+1\\
&=k^3+3k^2+3k+1\;.
\end{align*}$$

You can also organize this calculation like a pencil-and-paper multiplication:

$$\begin{array}{r}
&&k^2&+&2k&+&1\\
&&&&k&+&1\\ \hline
&&k^2&+&2k&+&1\\
k^3&+&2k^2&+&k\\ \hline
k^2&+&3k^2&+&3k&+&1
\end{array}$$

Comment: I'll add `\color` into my memory banks.

Answer (score 3):

You can write $(k^2+2k+1)(k+1)=k(k^2+2k+1)+1(k^2+2k+1)$ then distribute to get $k(k^2+2k+1)+1(k^2+2k+1)=k^3+2k^2+k+k^2+2k+1$ then collect like terms to get $k^3+3k^2+3k+1$.  This is more general than FOIL, which only handles the product of two items of two terms each.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a similar procedure and distribute the two binomial terms over the tri-nomial:

$$ \begin{align*}(k^2 + 2k + 1) (k+1) 
 &=  (k^2 + 2k^\hphantom{2} + 1) k +  (k^2 + 2k + 1) 1\\
 &=  \hphantom{(}k^3 + 2k^2 + k\hphantom{1)} +  \hphantom{(}k^2 + 2k + 1 \\
 &=  k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 \end{align*}$$

### Note:

- You have a mistake in the question: $(k+1)^2 = (k^2 + 2k + 1)$

Comment: Final line isn't correct...

Comment: @Epictetus: Yeah, I naively assumed that the beginning was correct in the problem.

Comment: Please don't call the expansion of a trinomial times a binomial *FOIL!*

Comment: @TheChaz: Corrected. Let me know if this is better.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is distributive over addition, so:

$$(k^2+2k+2)(k+1)=(k^2+2k+2)(k)+ (k^2+2k+2)(1) $$
$$=(k^3+2k^2+2k)+(k^2+2k+2)$$
Now, sum up like terms:
$$=k^3+3k^2+4k+2$$

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to learn how this [triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) works:

$$
1\\
1\,1\\
1\,2\,1\\
1\,3\,3\,1\\
1\,4\,6\,4\,1\\
1\,5\,10\,10\,5\,1
$$
The $n^{th}$ line (first one is zero) gives the coefficient of $x^{k}y^{n-k}$ in $(x+y)^n$

Since you had $(k+1)^3$, the coefficient are gonna be $1,3,3,1$ and now we have to figure out how to work the $k$.